# Android implement right to left navigation drawer with NavigationView

Tags: android

How can i open navigation drawer from right from 10+ api?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        android:touchscreenBlocksFocus="false"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
              android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Android Studio"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="android.studio@android.com"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately i could not found a solution in order to open navigation drawer from right, when i using `layout_gravity="right"` and `tools:openDrawer="right"` , i getting `No drawer view found with gravity LEFT` error, i think there is not any official way, should i still use `Recycle view` instead of `NavigationView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()` method, instead of calling the `ActionBarDrawerToggletoggle#onOptionsItemSelected()` method, we check if the `MenuItem`'s ID is equal to the Home `Button`'s ID, and toggle the drawer state ourselves.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if(drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Whichever `View` you use for the drawer doesn't really matter.